# How to get Resharper to list implicitly typed variables when Finding Usages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

When I do find usages on a type, the implicit typed variables of that type aren't included in the list. But if the same variable is explicitly typed, it gets included in the list of Usages.

See the results from Find Usages on MyType, below.

```
namespace Test
{
    public class MyType { }

    public class Test
    {
        public static MyType GetMyTypeInstance() => new MyType();

        public static void DemoFindUsageIssue()
        {
            var x = Test.GetMyTypeInstance();
            MyType y = Test.GetMyTypeInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

Find Usage result, see how the "var x" usage is not listed but the explicit one is:

```
Search Target
  Test.MyType
Found 3 usages in solution
  Test
    DemoFindUsageIssue():void (in Test)
      (12,4) MyType y = Test.GetMyTypeInstance();
    GetMyTypeInstance():MyType (in Test)
      (7,17) public static MyType GetMyTypeInstance() => new MyType();
      (7,51) public static MyType GetMyTypeInstance() => new MyType();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible in Resharper or Rider.

I have requested this feature from JetBrains support and they have stated that they do not have any immediate plans to implement this due to "possible performance degradation".